# Algorithm for maximizing happiness when distributing objects to 2 groups

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

You have an array of n fruits you must give to 2 people, X and Y. X will gain x_i happiness when eating the ith fruit, Y will gain y_i happiness when eating the ith fruit. We want to maximize total happiness of X and Y. The distribution of fruits does not have to be equal--you could give them all to X or all to Y.

You must give the fruit to X in Y in order (from the 1st to the nth fruit), and X and Y will ingest the fruit immediately upon receiving the fruit.

There is some difference in taste metric that affects how happy X and Y are to eat each fruit. This difference is defined by the function T(i,j), and is lookup-able in a table (costs O(1) to look up). So if X has just ingested fruit i, and is then given fruit j, X's happiness will increase by (x_j - T(i,j)).

I feel like this question should be solved via dynamic programming or maybe using a greedy algorithm but am having trouble formulating a solution. What I've done so far:

I know brute force is (2^n), since all combinations of fruit allocations to X and Y would be 2^n. I've tried doing a DP with [i,j,k] with i and j being the starting and ending fruits in n and k being the number of fruits you give to the first person (X). The solution with that DP would be max over k for any k of DP[0,n,k], but I can't seem to formulate beyond the base cases (am having trouble making the equation for DP[i,j,k])...

Comment: You should show *some* effort before asking the question here.

Comment: I've only been able to think of and prove brute force (2^n) so far :(

I've tried doing a DP with [i,j,k] with i and j being the starting and ending fruits in n and k being the number of fruits you give to the first person, but I can't seem to formulate beyond the base cases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved in quadratic time in *n* using dynamic programming. Let *f(i, j)* be the maximum possible happiness if last fruit eaten by X is *i* and last fruit eaten by Y is *j*. Let me call the first fruit the fruit number 0 and the last one the number *n - 1* (0-indexed). Then, you need to calculate *f(-1, -1)* (initially they have not eaten any fruit).

This dynamic programming can be easily calculated because if you know the last fruit eaten by both of them, you know the next fruit to be eaten.

The following C-like pseudocode has the details:

```
int dp(int i, int j) {
  //Get the current fruit
  int current = max(i, j) + 1;

  //Base case (I consider the first to be 0, so the last is n - 1)
  if (current == n) return 0;

  //Check if the value is calculated
  if (not calculated[i][j]) {
    calculated[i][j] = true;
    M[i][j] = max(dp(current, j) + x[current] - T(i, current), 
                  dp(i, current) + y[current] - T(j, current));
  }

  return M[i][j];
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! Is there also the case if i==j the solution should return -infinity (or something of the sort) though? Because we aren't supposed to be able to give both X and Y the same fruit.

Comment: Although it would not be wrong, it is not needed as this state cannot be reached if you start with dp(-1, -1) (apart from the original (-1, -1), which is special). This is because at each state we choose the next fruit (*current*) and we assign it to exactly one of them, so it is impossible to reach a state in which they have both eaten the same last fruit.